# Estimation of a sum involving Dirichlet character

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I want to show that :

$$\sum_{p\le x\\p^a \le x}\sum_{a=2}^{\infty}\frac{\chi(p^a)\log p}{p^a}=O(1)$$where , $\chi$ denotes the Dirichlet's character $\mod k$.

> We have, $\displaystyle \left | \sum_{p\le x\\p^a \le x}\sum_{a=2}^{\infty}\frac{\chi(p^a)\log p}{p^a}\right |\le \sum_{p \le x}\log p \sum_{a=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p^a}=\sum_{p\le x}\frac{\log p}{p(p-1)}<\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\log n}{n(n-1)}=O(1)$.

Is it correct ?

Comment: This looks right.

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: @DietrichBurde My  question is whether it is correct or not whichever I've done

Comment: Where exactly do you have doubts?

Comment: How I can show that the series $\sum \frac{\log n}{n(n-1)}$ is convergent ? Otherwise we can not write it as $O(1)$

Comment: You can prove the convergence of the series using the integral test or the Cauchy condensation test, for example.